# Sealed classes don't compile, Eclipse compiler bug?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-15, java-sealed-type

I am having those two classes in Eclipse 2020-09 and 2020-12:

Class A

```
package test;

public sealed class A permits B { }
```

Class B

```
package test;
import java.io.Serializable;

public final class B extends A implements Serializable  { }
```

However, the eclipse compiler is giving me a compiler error in class B:

> The type B extending a sealed class Serializable should be a permitted
> subtype of Serializable

This seems odd, as `Serializable` isn't even a sealed class. I find nothing about that in [JEP-360](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360).
Removing "implements Serializable" resolves that error.

Is that a bug in the Eclipse compiler?

Comment: What version of Eclipse? Various bugs in this area are marked as fixed in 2012-12

Comment: Yeah possibly so, the code just compiles fine with javac. Please mention the version as greg has asked for.

Comment: @greg-449  It is 2020-09. I have tried 2020-12, but it is unuseable due to other bug,

Comment: eclipse 2020-12 also has that bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else is reading this:

My [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=570218) has been fixed for Java 16.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if eclipse does fully support this (preview feature), but have you tried to use a command line compiler? (oracle or openjdk)

I just tested that code with Java 15.0.1 and it worked fine -> seams like eclipse is still not fully supporting that

Tested it with eclipse 2020-12 on another machine (had to be started first) - same error message [:-(

*much* probably it is a bug

Comment: *"have you tried to declare B as either final...."*... isn't that the code in question `public final class B ...`?

Comment: you are correct, somehow I didn't see it before (?)